# is there a difference between a remote and the location of the remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

Maybe I'm missing something about remotes, but this just puzzled me:
I have a git repo with a remote, the remote is in fact my USB stick.
On my remote, there is one commit more than in my local repo, so

```
 local-dir> git rev-list master -3
```

gives me

```
941eba8b82233f5daceb41a57e10ff2d6d893fb9 
8b386974a1976142912c41cc7e270e69ad5ecbd5
dd09efc70c029ea79fcfc455068df3788d4e193a
```

and

remote-dir> git rev-list master -4

gives me

```
28aaf69aafa9f21ad52c874d2e753bfd8e1b1f65                                   
941eba8b82233f5daceb41a57e10ff2d6d893fb9
8b386974a1976142912c41cc7e270e69ad5ecbd5
dd09efc70c029ea79fcfc455068df3788d4e193a
```

So far so good.

My remote is called `stick`. When I do

```
 local-dir> git rev-list stick/master -4
```

I get

```
a0e2cf2a389647768384259e3e8f5a7b310740d4
243a8b06b3df1f232dafb9385eab8336dea23f25
c316830bb4c5a27d29e01bbd734ab46f3d90a24e
bfd1dc912ab3c9f9d9bc5b10303b580305f68ac4
```

where further investigations reveals that "this way" I'm about 10 commits behind.
A `git fetch stick master` will not change the situation.

I had expected that `remote-dir> git rev-list master -4` and `local-dir> git rev-list stick/master -4` yield the same, at least after a fetch. Seems I'm missing something. Can someone explain what?

Comment: Is `git remote -v` == path of `local-dir`?

Comment: @BleedingFingers: `git remote -v`will give me `remote-dir` for push and fetch for `stick`. Not the `local-dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
git fetch stick master
```

acts differently in older gits than in the very newest ones.

It tells git to:

1. Look up the name `stick` as a remote (which finds the path to the USB stick).
2. Consult the remote—usually this would be over a network, but in this case, just go look in the other repository—to see what branches it has.
3. If the remote has a branch named `master` (which it does), gather up any commits and other objects required.
4. Finally (this is where the newest gits differ), write those *only* under the name `FETCH_HEAD` in the local repository; *do not* update the "remote-branch" information in `refs/remotes/stick/master`.

It's this last step that is causing confusion.

If you run instead:

```
git fetch stick
```

this will follow the first two steps, but for steps 3 and 4, it brings over *all* the branches and *does* update all the remote-branch information.  Then `git rev-list stick/master -4` will behave the way you expected it to.

If you upgrade to git 1.8.4 or newer, `git fetch` will update the remote-branch information in step 4 even with the two-argument `git fetch` form, and again it will behave the way you expected.

Here's what the release notes for 1.8.4 have to say about this:

> - "git fetch origin master" unlike "git fetch origin" or "git fetch"
>     did not update "refs/remotes/origin/master"; this was an early
>     design decision to keep the update of remote tracking branches
>     predictable, but in practice it turns out that people find it more
>     convenient to opportunistically update them whenever we have a
>     chance, and we have been updating them when we run "git push" which
>     already breaks the original "predictability" anyway.